# Eap 6.3 resteasy client: org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jboss, resteasy, jboss-eap-6

I'm developing an application on EAP 6.3. I need to invoke a rest service so I used pice of code like this:

```
ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(URL);
...
request.body(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, input);
... 
ClientResponse<String> response = request.post(String.class);
...
```

In my pom imported this bom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.bom.eap</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-resteasy</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0.GA</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

And than I defined the dependency with scope provided:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunatelly, running the previous code I get this error:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest from [Module "deployment.ats-ear.ear.ats-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 87 more
```

Looking on the server in *modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\main* actually there is the jar *resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar* that contains the class: *org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest*

I don't get what I'm doing wrong... mayde I need to specify something in the in *jbooss-deployment-structure.xml*?

If I set the scope of resteasy-jaxrs as compile, everthing works fine, but I don't think is a good idea to put in my ear a library already present on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding the proper modules in *jboss-deployment-structure.xml*:

```
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        ....
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" export="true" meta-inf="export" slot="main"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" export="true" meta-inf="export" slot="main"/>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>

<sub-deployment name="ats-web.war">
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
```